# Images with Interval for animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm going to use if else for creating an animation with a certain interval for each image but it's not working, it made me confused please anyone tell me what's wrong with my code. Here is my code:

```js
var j = setInterval(james, 5);

function james() {
  var pos = 1;
  if (pos >= 6) {
    clearInterval(j);
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', 'https://www.ptcrush.com/' + pos + '.gif');
  } else {
    var pos += 1;
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', 'https://www.ptcrush.com/' + pos + '.gif');
  }
}
```

```html
<img />
<button onclick="james()">Halo</button>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should move the initialization of `pos` outside the function. You reset it to `1` every time you call the function, so it's never `>=6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code in a working example.

Here are a few pointers as to what I improved:

1. Move `pos` out of the function as each time it is called, it will be reset to 1.
2. No need to clear the interval unless you want to stop the animation after one round.
3. remove var in the else statement. As you already define it above, there's no need to do it again. Only use `var`, `let` or `const` the first time you initiate a variable.
4. I've increased the interval to 3 seconds `setInterval(james, 3000)` else the animation would be running too fast. Tweak as you see fit.

```js
var j = setInterval(james, 3000);

var pos = 1;

function james() {
  if (pos >= 6) {
    pos = 1;
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', 'https://www.ptcrush.com/' + pos + '.gif');
  } else {
    pos += 1;
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', 'https://www.ptcrush.com/' + pos + '.gif');
  }
}
```

```html
<img />
<p><button onclick="james()">Hallo</button></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `var` from line:

```
var pos += 1;
```

Also move the variable initialization to outside the function:

```
var pos = 1;
function james() {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put outside the function the variable `pos` and you need to increase the timeout because by the time your new image will load, the timer will load a new image

```js
var pos = 1;
var j = setInterval(james, 4000);

function james() {
  if (pos >= 6) {
    clearInterval(j);
    document
      .getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
      .setAttribute('src', 'https://www.ptcrush.com/' + pos + '.gif');
  } else {
    pos += 1;
    document
      .getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
      .setAttribute('src', 'https://www.ptcrush.com/' + pos + '.gif');
  }
  console.log('pos', pos);
}
```

```html
<img width="200" height="200" src="" />
```